# INSERT doesn't work in pymysql, but SELECT does just fine

Tags: python, mysql, database, jupyter-notebook, pymysql

I'm working in a Jupyter Notebook and using pymysql. I can read off that database, so the connection must be established, but I can't send any INSERT statements.

```
connection = pymysql.connect(endpoint, user, passwd, db)
insert = [('Popowice',363000),('Wroclaw',389991),('Biskupin',359000)]
sql = "INSERT INTO housing_wroclaw (`District`, `Price`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany(sql,insert)
```

This piece of code with my credentials returns 3 - the number of insert tuples and no errors. But the database just doesn't have those records. I tried also looping through values using execute() rather than executemany(), but neither worked and the latter is apparently better.

Below is my working SELECT statement:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * from housing_wroclaw')

rows = cursor.fetchall()
```

How can I INSERT? Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call **connection.commit()** after inserting data to make it persistent.

Comment: Btw, I've read about closing the connection - is that also necessary?

Comment: Closing the connection is best practice after work done at DB. It helps to release memory and TCP connection for both client and DB server.